# Change an iOS app after appstore launch

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Are there any libraries or services for iOS to change a live (in the appstore) iPhone app UI?

The only way I can see it working now is to use a web view, but I would rather have a native solution.

Comment: There's a 2010 WWDC session video on database driven app design that show how to do this (downloadable UI configuration, as presented by Apple, so hopefully complying with their App Store rules).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you can control the UI style by using CSS properties (like styling a web page).  If you design your app with this approach, then you could store that CSS file on a server.  When the app launches, you can tell it to read the CSS file from the server and style it's interface accordingly.  Thus if you made any changes in the CSS file, those changes would be reflected in the UI when the app is launched again.

Here's a link explaining the CSS approach to style buttons, tables, etc..

see the webpage: [NUI for iOS - Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nui)

Comment: I would worry about this, insofar as apple could claim that you're downloading and executing code. +1, anyhow, this is the best solution.

Comment: Well it wouldn't hurt to try it. I might actually give it a go myself and see if Apple accepts it.

Comment: Apple doesn't have your sources and they don't know that you use a CSS to draw your interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you could be more specific on "change" you can do anything you want if you're pulling data from a server or website. You'll only need to update the website, have the app ask for the data or an update, and the app will receive the new data.

Comment: I was thinking of UI changes mostly. Basically so I can iterate on design and functionality without having to push a new build to the appstore and then sit and wait for 1-2 weeks for approval. You can do that easily with web views but you lose the ability to have native functionality.

Comment: Definitely, you can set up a view to take multiple sizes, set imageViews to take different images, or whatever you want. However you need to build the app to accept these data packets before hand.

Answer (score 0):

What i have done for some of my public and non public applications is to host a plist file on an amazon s3 server, very cost effective, even better if you have your own web server.  I will then parse that plist and have set up an architecture in my applications which will build the interface depending on the instructions for the plist.  As a simple example, lets say you want to decide on your application background color via a web pull.  You can have a dictionary in the plist file which will store 4 values with the keys backgroundR, backgroundB, backgroundG, backgroundA (RGB value and alpha).  You can then parse the plist file and fill a UIColor with the rgb and alpha values and set it as the background color.  Don't forget to have built in default values in case the file can not be reached.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Gavin you can use CSS Styling tools like [NUI](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/nui), or the more polished [nativeCSS](http://nativecss.com) to change the appearance of a native app after it's been released.

I've had nativeCSS apps through the app store and operate in this way. This doesn't really provide a functional change to the app, but allows areas to be unlocked when they are ready.